# Positive realness conditions for solutions of a quadratic equation

Tags: calculus, analysis

The following system of algebraic equations arises from simple eigenvalue problem in mechanics:
\begin{align*}
\frac{{{c}_{1}}^2+{x _{1}}^2}{{{c}_{1}}^2+{x _{2}}^2}-\frac{1}{a_1^2}&=0,\\
\frac{{{c}_{2}}^2+{x _{1}}^2}{{{c}_{2}}^2+{x _{2}}^2}-\frac{1}{a_2^2}&=0.
\end{align*}
We are looking for **real** (finite) solutions $x_1,x_2$ of the system such that
\begin{equation}
x_1>0,\quad x_2>0,\quad x_1^2\neq x_2^2.\tag{1}\label{eq01} 
\end{equation}
For the parameters $a_1,a_2,c_1,c_2$ we assume that they are all real and positive.

Now, the solutions $x_1,x_2$ are directly found to be:
\begin{align*}
x_1&=\sqrt{\dfrac{\left(1-a_1^2\right)c_1^2-\left(1-a_2^2\right)c_2^2}{a_1^2-a_2^2}},\\[1em]
x_2&=\sqrt{\dfrac{a_2^2\left(1-a_1^2\right)c_1^2-a_1^2\left(1-a_2^2\right)c_2^2}{a_1^2-a_2^2}},
\end{align*}
The questions then are: (i) What conditions must be placed on $a_1,a_2,c_1,c_2$ so that the conditions in \eqref{eq01} hold? Is there a **single** condition on the parameters that must be true in both the solutions such that the conditions in \eqref{eq01} hold?

Comment: Given that all of the $a_i$ and $c_i$ terms are squared, it doesn't look like it matters whether they are positive or negative, provided that they're not both zero.  Since your expression for the $x_i$ involves a square root, I would assume that it's merely physical reasoning which is driving you to choose positive $x_i$.  That $x_{1}^{2} \ne x_{2}^{2}$ implies that the two numerators of the square roots are not equal.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, in fact, showing that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are complex for certain values of $a_1$, $a_2$, $c_1$, $c_2$. There are plenty of combinations of these leading to complex $x_i$, e.g. $a_1=8$, $a_2=9$, $c_1=20$, $c_2=26$. We need to find conditions on those ranges of parameters that would lead to positive real $x_i$. This seems to be more difficult than it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I cracked the problem via some elemntary calculations. All in all we need to consider four cases: (i) $a_2<a_1<1$; (ii) $a_1<a_2<1$; (iii) $1<a_1<a_2$; and (iv) $1<a_2<a_1$. The statement then reads as follows:

In order that $x_1,x_2>0$ and $x_1^2\neq x_2^2$ the following conditions must hold:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ll}
&\dfrac{c_1^2}{c_2^2}>\dfrac{a_1^2\left(1-a_2^2\right)}{a_2^2\left(1-a_1^2\right)}&\text{under condition (i)}\\[1em]
&\dfrac{c_1^2}{c_2^2}<\dfrac{a_1^2\left(1-a_2^2\right)}{a_2^2\left(1-a_1^2\right)}&\text{under condition (ii)}\\[1em]
&\dfrac{c_1^2}{c_2^2}>\dfrac{1-a_2^2}{1-a_1^2}&\text{under condition (iii)}\\[1em]
&\dfrac{c_1^2}{c_2^2}<\dfrac{1-a_2^2}{1-a_1^2}&\text{under condition (iv)}\\[1em]
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
I hope the statement is correct.